# Invalid property [hideChatterActions] in component [force:highlightsPanel]

Tags: lightning-experience, deployment, change-set

**Invalid property [hideChatterActions] in component [force:highlightsPanel] while we deploy the lighting pages from sandbox to production.**

How we can get rid this error ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I work for Gearset and we've seen this error crop up a little in the past few days. It's a Salesforce metadata API bug where it looks like metadata from the newer version is leaked via earlier versions of the API, regardless of which API version you make your metadata retrieve request with. This means that until the bug is fixed, to successfully deploy these lightning pages you have to remove the Highlights panel from each page and then you'll be able to deploy as usual. Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

I have come across the error while deploying the changeset having a flexipage of type record page. What happens is the Production org api version is 46.0(summer 19) whereas the sandbox api version is 47.0(winter 20).

My page was having large number of components with the filtered condition.  How I get rid of the error?

I have used VS Code to retrieve the flexipage locally into my project folder. Then I removed the **hideChatterActions** property from metadata of flexipage and redeployed the flexipage to the sandbox.

As now sandbox no longer contains the **hideChatterActions** property in its metadata, it allows me to successfully upload the changeset.

> Note:- hideChatterActions property have been recently introduced to
>   hide or show the follow button on record page.